# how to run a bat or PS1 file while VM's booting

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have a script to assign static IP address to HyperV VM's whenever it found 169.x.x.x series IP,and the script start work when we logged in to the machine as Administrator.

Is it possible to run the script while machine booting ? So that, we don't need to log in to the VM's to run the script ?

Comment: You mesan like a startup script?

Answer (score -1):

You don't give us any information about your deployment process. But you could essentially use the `SetupComplete.cmd`. Run your PowerShell script from there.

See [Add a Custom Script to Windows Setup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766314(v=ws.10).aspx).